# I need help comparing files in a directory recursively to find duplicates

Tags: java, file-io

I'm working on a program that will (hopefully) compare all files in a given directory, identify duplicates, add them to a list, then display the list to the user so they can verify they want those files deleted before deleting them and I'm seriously stuck. So far I've been able to recursively list all the files and I've been messing around with comparing them to find the duplicates. I'm quickly realizing to accomplish what I want I'm going to need to compare more than one file attribute. Not all files will be text files and comparing text is mostly what I've found as far as example code on the internet goes, I'm trying learn more about the binary data because comparing byte arrays and file names is the best I could come up with. Specifically I'm asking which attributes would be best to compare in order to balance accuracy in finding the duplicates and being able to handle a reasonable sized directory? And if you don't mind how could I implement it in my code? Hopefully my question wasn't too terrible, I'd really appreciate any help I can get. Here's what I have, and yes, a couple of the methods and the second file I did find here in case you were wondering.
P.S. I'm really sorry about the pointless variables if I missed any, I tried to clean up the code a little before posting it

ListFilesInDir.java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.attribute.*;
import java.security.*;
import java.util.*;

public final class ListFilesInDir {

static File startingDir;

static List<File> files;
static List<File> dirs;
static TreeMap<Integer, File> duplicates;
static ArrayList<Integer> usedIndexes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
static ArrayList<File> duplicateList = new ArrayList<File>();

static File out = new File("ListDuplicateFiles.txt");
static PrintWriter output;

static int key = 0;
static String tabString;
static TreeMap<Integer, File> tMap = new TreeMap<Integer, File>();

static int num1 = 0;
static int num2 = 0;
static File value1 = null;
static File value2 = null;
static String path1 = null;
static String name1 = null;
static String path2 = null;
static String name2 = null;

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    new ListFilesInDir(args[0]);
}

public ListFilesInDir(String string) throws FileNotFoundException {
    startingDir = new File(string);
    dirs = new ArrayList<File>();
    duplicates = new TreeMap<Integer, File>();
    output = new PrintWriter(out);

    getFiles(startingDir);
    compareFiles();
    writeDuplicateList();
}

public void getFiles(File root) throws FileNotFoundException {
    System.out.println("Adding files to list...");
    ListFilesInDir.files = getFileList(root);
    for (File file : files) {
        if (!file.isFile()) {
            System.out.println("Adding DIR: " + key + " name: " + file);
            dirs.add(file);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Adding FILE: " + key + " name: " + file);
            tMap.put(key, file);
        }
        key++;
    }
    System.out.println(dirs.size());
    System.out.println("Complete");
}

public static void compareFiles() throws FileNotFoundException {
    System.out.println("Preparing to compare files...");
    for (num1 = 0; num1 < files.size(); num1++) {
        for (num2 = 0; num2 < files.size(); num2++) {

            if (num1 != num2) {
                value1 = files.get(num1);
                value2 = files.get(num2);
                path1 = value1.getAbsolutePath();
                path2 = value2.getAbsolutePath();
                name1 = path1.substring(path1.lastIndexOf(File.separator));
                name2 = path2.substring(path2.lastIndexOf(File.separator));
                HashMap<Integer, File> testMap = new HashMap<Integer, File>();

                System.out.println(num1 + "|" + num2 + " : " + value1
                        + " - " + value2);
                if (CompareBinaries.fileContentsEquals(
                        value1.getAbsolutePath(), value2.getAbsolutePath()) == true) {
                    if (testMap.put(num1, value1) != null) {
                        TreeSet<File> fileTreeSet;
                    }
                    addDuplicate(num1, value1);
                    files.remove(num1);

                    System.out.println("added(binary): " + num1 + ":"
                            + value1);

                } else if (value1.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(
                        value2.getName())) {
                    addDuplicate(num1, value1);
                    files.remove(num1);
                    System.out.println("added(name): " + num1 + ":"
                            + value1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Complete");

}

public static void writeDuplicateList() {
    int printKey = 0;
    for (File file : duplicateList) {
        output.printf("%03d | %s\n", printKey, file);
        System.out.printf("%03d | %s\n", printKey, file);
        printKey++;
    }

    output.append(docsInfo());
    output.close();
    output.flush();

    System.out.println("\n"+files.size()+" files in "+startingDir.getAbsolutePath() +", "+duplicateList.size()+" duplicate files.");
}

static public String docsInfo() {
    String s = "\n\n" + files.size() + " files in "
            + startingDir.getAbsolutePath() + ", " + duplicates.size()
            + " duplicate files.";
    return s;
}

static public List<File> getFileList(File file)
        throws FileNotFoundException {
    List<File> result = getUnsortedFileList(file);
    Collections.sort(result);
    return result;
}

static private List<File> getUnsortedFileList(File file)
        throws FileNotFoundException {
    List<File> result = new ArrayList<File>();
    File[] filesAndDirs = file.listFiles();
    List<File> filesDirs = Arrays.asList(filesAndDirs);
    int dirKey = 0;

    for (File fileList : filesDirs) {
        result.add(fileList);
        if (!fileList.isFile()) {

            List<File> deeperList = getUnsortedFileList(fileList);
            result.addAll(deeperList);
        }
    }
    return result;
    }

        static private void validateDir(File dir) throws FileNotFoundException {
    if (dir == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Directory is null!");
    if (!dir.exists())
        throw new FileNotFoundException("Directory doesn't exist: " + dir);
    if (!dir.isDirectory())
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(dir + "is not a directory!");
    if (!dir.canRead())
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Directory cannot be read: "
                + dir);
     }

         public static void addDuplicate(int i, File file)throws FileNotFoundException{
          if (!duplicates.containsKey(i)) {
           duplicates.put(i, file);
               duplicateList.add(file);

          }
     }
    }
```

CompareBinaries.java

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Arrays;


public class CompareBinaries {

private final static int BUFFSIZE = 1024;
private static byte buff1[] = new byte[BUFFSIZE];
private static byte buff2[] = new byte[BUFFSIZE];

public static boolean inputStreamEquals(InputStream is1, InputStream is2) {
    if(is1 == is2) return true;

    if(is1 == null && is2 == null) {
        System.out.println("both input streams are null");
        return true;
    }

    if(is1 == null || is2 == null) return false;
    try {
        int read1 = -1;
        int read2 = -1;

        do {
            int offset1 = 0;
            while (offset1 < BUFFSIZE
                        && (read1 = is1.read(buff1, offset1, BUFFSIZE-offset1)) >= 0) {
                        offset1 += read1;
                }

            int offset2 = 0;
            while (offset2 < BUFFSIZE
                        && (read2 = is2.read(buff2, offset2, BUFFSIZE-offset2)) >= 0) {
                        offset2 += read2;
                }
            if(offset1 != offset2) return false;
            if(offset1 != BUFFSIZE) {
                Arrays.fill(buff1, offset1, BUFFSIZE, (byte)0);
                Arrays.fill(buff2, offset2, BUFFSIZE, (byte)0);
            }
            if(!Arrays.equals(buff1, buff2)) return false;
        } while(read1 >= 0 && read2 >= 0);
        if(read1 < 0 && read2 < 0) return true; // both at EOF
        return false;

    } catch (Exception ei) {
        return false;
    }
}

public static boolean fileContentsEquals(File file1, File file2) {
    InputStream is1 = null;
    InputStream is2 = null;
    if(file1.length() != file2.length()) return false;

    try {
        is1 = new FileInputStream(file1);
        is2 = new FileInputStream(file2);

        return inputStreamEquals(is1, is2);

    } catch (Exception ei) {
        return false;
    } finally {
        try {
            if(is1 != null) is1.close();
            if(is2 != null) is2.close();
        } catch (Exception ei2) {}
    }
}

public static boolean fileContentsEquals(String fn1, String fn2) {
    return fileContentsEquals(new File(fn1), new File(fn2));
}
```

}

Comment: "And if you don't mind how could I implement it in my code" = plz send teh codez

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an hash function to compare two files - two files (in a different folder) can have same name and attributes (eg length) but different content. For example, you can create a text file and then copy it on a different folder changing one letter in the content.

An hash function does some clever maths on the file content ending up with a number, even small difference in content will end up with two very different numbers.

Taking for example the md5 hash function, this produces a 16 bytes number out of a byte array of any length. While it is theoretically possible to create two files with the same md5 but different content, the probability is very low (while two files with same name and size but different content is a relatively high probability event)

The point is, you can build a table of md5 of file contents, this has to be calculated only once and it is quick to compare - if the md5 are different, the files are different with an 100% confidence. Only in the unlikely event the md5 are the same you will have to resort to byte-by-byte comparison to be 100% sure.

Comment: I thought md5 was just an encryption algorithm, but that sounds brilliant. Is there any chance you can recommend a book or know of a place on the web I could learn more? I mean other than the API, of course I'm going to go check that out. I was concerned about comparing files byte for byte and the amount of time it might take but that might actually be possible if the md5 function returns a small enough list of duplicates. Thanks a lot, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Hashing is used a lot in cryptography, however there are many other uses - have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function

Comment: In particular, if you are using java, the Object class has an essential method you MUST override in most cases: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode also see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_hashCode

Comment: I'll hit the books as soon as I get home from work. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

On Working on my Project work recently, I had found a 
good memo on receiving the duplicate filenames and directory 
using SHA algorithm

take a look on it :
https://jakut.is/2011/03/15/a-java-program-to-list-all/

May be it might be useful for you

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion: Walk thru one directory tree, compare to the other directory tree by name. Then, for each matching pair, compare file size and last-modificagtion-time and, if all that is equal, do a straight forward byte-by-byte comparison.

There're two steps to implement this (if added links to example code):

1. Walk thru both directories to get the full list. Java has speed up this with Java 7 and the [`Files.walkFileTree()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/walk.html). You walk thru one directory tree and compare each entry to the other directory tree. I've posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18211580/2435872) some example code for such a comparison (My example code should help you with this step, yet does not 100% hit your question)
2. Compare two files if they equal or not. Several things can be compared:

   - File name. This is obvious, as it is needed to find the file in the second tree anyway.
   - File size, last modification time: Are part of the `BasicFileAttributes` that you get, when walking the tree. See example code on how to get it for the second file.
   - The content. As mentioned above you can calculate some kind of crc, md5, sha. What happens is, that you'll read the full content of both files. So, my suggestion here is, to directly compare byte-by-byte, e.g. with [`Arrays.equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals(byte[], byte[]))